# Why I am getting the Browser Sign in dialog box?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms

I am currently trying to upgrade a very old ASP.Net Web Forms Solution to a new security provider (okta).

When I start running the application locally using Visual Studio, I get prompted to sign in. The Sign In window / dialog box is the default from browser.  Below is an example for Chrome. But, I get something similar from Edge and IE.

[image]

After I enter my network / domain username password, I continue to Site.Master.

This behavior is only for this ASP.Net Web Forms Application. If I create new Web Forms project, I do not get this behavior.

Which would leave me to believe it is something about this solution.  However, if I publish the solutions to a QA box, I don’t get prompted by the browser to Sign In.

Is there a setting in the Solution? (I have been looking at it for hours.)

Is there a browser setting?

This is an issue because, after I sign in, HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated equals true.  And I do want to be authenticated using the browser. I want to redirect to my new security provider (okta) to sign in. Which will set IsAuthenticated to true.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at IIS express configurations: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` Make sure authentication settings are correct and not affecting you. There should not be any entry for your application. Also the default value for windows authentication should be false: `<windowsAuthentication enabled="false">`

Comment: You could set breakpoints at the start page's `Page_Load()` to check which function raise the prompt window in browser. Besides, there's [an article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/) about using browser's native login prompt. You could check if the project uses HTTP Basic Authentication Protocol which leads to the prompt window showing in browser.

Comment: @Yu Zhou Thanks for the comment. But, I do not every get to the Page_Load before the Sign In Dialog Box shows. I can't ever get into Site.Master.  Something is causes the dialog box to show before I can even debug the solution.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I found the file and played around with the setting.  Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the issue using method. But, it did make me think about it from a different angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow developer was able to help me with this issue.  In Visual Studio, I opened the Properties Window. I set Anonymous Authentication to Enabled and Windows Authentication to Disabled.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.